# images not showing on my LEMP stack

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, laravel-5.4

I have a site which is on Digital Ocean and the site is setup on a LEMP stack.  Now some of the images are not showing on the site.  When I run this in development it works.  Although, when now it is in production the images aren't shown.  I have read to install GD Graphics Library for Ubuntu.  I did this with the following command `sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd`  Then I restarted the server `sudo service nginx restart`.  When I go to the site nothing has changed.  Is there something I am doing wrong.

Comment: are getting any errors ?? check the log files , check the browser console to see if there is any errors

Comment: This is the error I have got `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` For each of the images.

Comment: Does this mean the images have not been loaded?

Comment: so make sure that the images exists on the right location and check the links of the images  by inspecting the source!

Comment: I think I have spotted it.  The images are in lower case in the public folder and the HTML shows it in uppercase.

Comment: so this might be the case try to fix that and make sure that you are not changing the image url case to upper with php !

Comment: Timino can you put "Check the log files as the answer".  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on you comment :

1. check out the error log file.
2. and make sure that images links are correct by checking the browser console .
3. make sure that images exists on the right location.